# Is this LED light fixture compatible with a dimmer switch? (Photo attached)

Tags: led, dimmer-switch, recessed-lighting

[image: Light fixture]

I have three of these recessed LED light fixtures on the ceiling of my apartment kitchen (Virginia, USA, brand new construction). All three lights are controlled by one switch. They are extremely bright. Am I able to install and use a dimmer switch with these lights? I was not able to move the plastic box or metal bracket to show more of the text.

I believe the part number is LT-DDY15W-35V-C300-V2. There's no other product markings on the part. I was not able to find any information online using this part number.

Thank you!

Comment: There is no brand marking at all? You may have to contact the landlord to find out. However, since you're renting, you're not allowed to do any electrical work beyond changing lightbulbs. You can burn down you own house by miswiring something, but they look down on you burning down other people's houses (apartments) by accidentally miswiring something. TL;DR: Ask your landlord

Comment: If your landlord is unwilling to bring in a licensed electrician (or you’re unwilling to pay the bill), you could dim the lights with a (removable) filter.

Answer (score 3):

Other units that I could find which use the same power supply part number support dimming, so I suspect this luminaire will work fine with a dimmer. To truly confirm you will need the part number.

That doesn't allow you to do wiring on a rented apartment, though. For that (implied) part of the question, you do need to confirm with your property manager that it's OK to swap out the switch. I suspect they will want to have an electrician do it so they stay compliant with the local codes.